# Why Does My Mac Terminal Say I have 218 Tabs Open?

Tags: macos, terminal

[image]

I read that the number in the red circle is how many tabs I have open, but I only have 2 Terminal windows open. Can anyone tell me why this number is so high? I'm currently doing some C programming homework, so I'm wondering if the #include statements in my .c files are making this number higher.

Comment: Thanks! I just wanted to upvote him first and comment under his answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The red circle is not the number of tabs you have open, but instead the number of alerts (bells) that have happened in the terminal window since you have visited/cleared them.

This can happen if you have a program like grunt daemon running and get an error, which it reports via this mechanism.

Comment: Ohhh ok. Is having a number this high bad for the system? Will it make my system slower? How do I clear them?

Comment: Nope. It won't hurt having this number be very high.  The good news is it's just a counter, it's not actually running processes.